# Nested looping around an array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I am trying to loop all the values of an array and push that looped data into another array.

For example:

```
{
"cat": [
    {
        "view": [
            {
                "ent": [
                    {
                        "data": [
                            {}
                        ],
                        "label": "abcd"
                    },
                    {
                        "data": [
                            {}
                        ],
                        "label": "efgh"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

I need to iterate until label and bring all the values of label into an array. This is what I have tried.
The issue is I am just getting the last value of label i.e. won in my array variable.

JS:

```
var ArrL = scope.res.cat;
var Array = [];
for(var i=0;i<ArrL.length;i++){
    var ArrF = ArrL[i].view;
    for(var j=0;j<ArrF.length;j++){
        var ArrE = ArrF[j].ent;
        for(var k=0;k<ArrE.length;k++){
            var ArrLa = ArrE[k].label;

        }

    }
    Array.push(ArrLa);
}
console.log(Array);
```

Expected output is `['joy','won']` but output after running the program is `['won']`.

Comment: Where you have defined `ArrLa`?

Comment: seems an invalid `json` structure. `},]`.

Comment: It's not JSON at all, just a normal array. Trailing commas are bad form but work in most JS engines.

Comment: I just added the basic JSON, its not an actual JSON structure. ArrLa is just a variable.... Declared all the variables without var keyword

Comment: Trailing commas are lazy and fail big time in IE<9

Comment: `}],
         label: "won"` what is getting closed above `label:"won"`

Comment: @mplungjan—only in an Object literal, in an Array literal a single trailing comma is incorrectly treated as an elision (in IE<9, not by others).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your Q is flagged as jquery, you can do this:

```
var cat = [
    {
        view: [
            {
                ent: [
                    {
                        data: [
                            {
                                key: "id",
                                value: "00"
                            }, 
                            {
                                key: "cid",
                                value: "123"
                            }
                        ],
                        label: "joy"
                    }, 
                    {
                        key: "id",
                        value: "11"
                    }, 
                    {
                        key: "cid",
                        value: "234"
                    }
                ], // end ent
                label: "won"
            }, 

        ] //end view
    }
];

var labels = [];

$.map( cat, function flattener( node ) {
    if ( $.isPlainObject( node ) && node.hasOwnProperty('label') ) {
        labels.push( node.label );
    }
    return ($.isArray( node ) || $.isPlainObject( node )) ? $.map( node, flattener) : node;
} );

console.log( labels );
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/fFwQ6/

Thing to note is that order will be dictated by depth: deeper labels come last.

UPDATE:
It is easy to turn it into an utility function:

```
function grabKeys( source, keyName ) {
    var values = [];

    $.map( source, function flattener( node ) {
        if ( $.isPlainObject( node ) && node.hasOwnProperty(keyName) ) {
            values.push( node[keyName] );
        }
        return ($.isArray( node ) || $.isPlainObject( node )) ? $.map( node, flattener) : node;
    } );

    return values;
}


var labels = grabKeys( cat, 'label' );
var cids = grabKeys( cat, 'cid' );
```

UPDATE 2: Since 'cid' is a key value and not a name, we must use a slightly different method. Sorry I did not noticed it previously.

```
function grabPairedKeys( source, keyValue, keyName1, keyName2 ) {
    keyName1 = keyName1 || 'key';
    keyName2 = keyName2 || 'value';

    var values = [];

    $.map( source, function flattener( node ) {
        if ( $.isPlainObject( node ) && node.hasOwnProperty(keyName1) && node.hasOwnProperty(keyName2) && node[keyName1] === keyValue ) {
            values.push( node[keyName2] );
        }
        return ($.isArray( node ) || $.isPlainObject( node )) ? $.map( node, flattener) : node;
    } );

    return values;
}


var labels = grabKeys( cat, 'label' );
var cids = grabPairedKeys( cat, 'cid' );
```

Comment: Thank you very much brother, your code is very minimal and gives the accurate values. If I need to have the value for the key "cid" along with label how to modify the code.

Comment: Thank you very much once again.... Expected output should be cid:["234","123"] and label:["won","joy"]. I am getting output only for label but not for cid, I changed the code of your previous fiddle and tried by replacing it with the updated one. Can you please attach the fiddle of expecting result. I am very much thankful to you....

Comment: Update 2 added. There was a small misconception.

Answer (score 1):

You should use the push in the loop.

```
    for(var i=0;i<ArrL.length;i++){
                ArrF = ArrL[i].view;
                for(var j=0;j<ArrF.length;j++){
                    ArrE = ArrF[j].ent;
                    for(var k=0;k<ArrE.length;k++){
                        ArrLa = ArrE[k].label;
                        Array.push(ArrLa);
                    }

                }

            }
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, you only push the last value that was assigned to `ArrLa` after having iterated the `view` array. Instead, push the value right away when you encounter it:

```
var Array = [];
for(var i=0;i<ArrL.length;i++){
    var ArrF = ArrL[i].view;
    for(var j=0;j<ArrF.length;j++){
        var ArrE = ArrF[j].ent;
        for(var k=0;k<ArrE.length;k++){
             Array.push(ArrE[k].label);
        }
    }
}
console.log(Array);
```